# Running hadoop command gives a "permission denied" error

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to run `bin/hadoop namenode -format` in Ubuntu 12.10 as a root user. But a "Permission Denied" error occurred. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you are entering the correct password.

Comment: you shouldn't run it as root user but as hduser user if you created it within the hadoop group.

Answer (score 0):

The hadoop user doesn't have access this shall fix your issue

```
sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop /usr/local/hadoop
```